# How to make sure strings would not overlap each other in java processing?

Tags: string, random, processing, overlap, overlapping

I'm having a problem that I need to make the words I took from an external file "NOT" overlap each other. I have over 50 words that have random text sizes and places when you run it but they overlap.

How can I make them "NOT" overlap each other? the result would probably look like a word cloud.

if you think my codes would help here they are

```java
   String [] words;
    int index = 0;

   void setup () 
     {

      size (500,500);
      background (255); 
      String [] lines = loadStrings ("alice_just_text.txt"); 
      String entireplay = join(lines, " "); //splits it by line
      words = splitTokens (entireplay, ",.?!:-;:()03 "); //splits it by word

      for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) { 

      float x = random(width);
      float y = random(height);
      int index = int(random(words.length));  
      textSize (random(60)); //random font size
      fill (0); 
      textAlign (CENTER);
      text (words[index], x, y, width/2, height/2);
      println(words[index]); 
      index++ ;
      }

   }
```

Comment: @KenWhite thank you! I didn't know how to edit a post yet because I am new in stockoverflow... thank you though :) I will be editing it now and deleting my comments that are not necessary

Comment: You'll find an [edit] link right below the tags in the lower left corner of your question. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite oh my! found it! thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. You'll have much better luck if you post a more specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type question. But I'll try to help in a general sense:

You need to [break your problem down into smaller pieces](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and then take on those pieces one at a time.

For example, you can isolate your problem to making sure **rectangles** don't overlap, which you can break down even further. There are a number of ways to do that:

You could use a grid to lay out your rectangles. Figure out how many squares a line of text takes up, then find a place in your grid where that word will fit. You could use something like a 2D array of boolean values, for example.

Or you could generate a random location, and then check whether there's already a rectangle there. If so, pick a new random location until you find a clear spot.

In any case, you'll probably need to use [collision detection](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/collision-detection) (either point-rectangle or rectangle-rectangle) to determine whether your rectangles are overlapping.

Start small. Create a small example program that just shows two rectangles on the screen. Hardcode their positions at first, but make it so they turn red if they're colliding. Work your way up from there. Make it so you can add rectangles using the mouse, but only let the user add them if there is no overlap. Then add the random location choosing. If you get stuck on a specific step, then post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we'll go from there. Good luck.